# How to get the total number of documents stored inside MongoDB collection using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection called 'archives' in DB called 'data' and all I want is to use PHP to get a total count of documents in this collection. The following doesn't work:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://username:psw@127.0.0.1:27017');

$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(
        ['count' => 'archives', 
]);

$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('data', $command);

$count = current($cursor->toArray())->values;
```

Any ideas on how to get a simple count of all documents?

Comment: Let me search for you: [PHP MongoDB Count Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702331/php-mongodb-count-records)

Comment: @AlexBlex I tried all of that... nothing works. BTW. the example you provided is not even related, it counts total in the past hour, I just want a simple representation in PHP for something so simple as db.archives.count()

Comment: Please put some efforts to read the code in the duplicated question and adjust the filter as needed. If you can't reproduce the accepted solution, provide some details in which way it fails. "Doesn't work" is not a problem statement. For the "simple" syntax use  mongodb library `composer require mongodb/mongodb` instead of working with the driver directly.

Comment: It's obvious you have never tried that code. That's not the path, I could never get it working even with the time constrains... I am, however, trying to do this my own way to do the aggregate and count instead, but I was hoping someone here would know an answer to something as that.

Comment: Of course I did not and I strongly recommend to never run random code from the internet forums. I learned it the hard way many years ago. The code from this question https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linux.org.ru%2Fforum%2Fdevelopment%2F392747 wipes out the hard drive. I do confirm that the answer from the duplicate question works and returns correct number of documents. If you have any problems with that code please share in which way it doesn't work for you precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another way to get the count from stats:

```
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["dbstats" => 1]);
$res = $manager->executeCommand("data", $command);
$stats = current($res->toArray());
print_r($stats->objects);
```

Comment: It's very fast and efficient way to get number of documents. Bear in mind that it's not exactly accurate https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown

Comment: I've done some testing and got the correct number every single time, but I guess if there is a lot of transactions, that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around, I had to use aggregate to get the count.
Not a pretty solution, but the only thing that would replicate db.archives.count() functionality through PHP:

```
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'archives',
    'pipeline' => [
        [ '$group' => [ '_id' => null, 'count' => [ '$sum'=> 1 ]]]
    ],
    'cursor' => new stdClass,
]);
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('data', $command);
$result_array = $cursor->toArray();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_array);
echo '</pre>';
```